# Exchange Web Service Managed API: How to read From Email Address?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Service Managed API 1.1 version for some of my development task, I want to perform some operations on the incoming email message.

1. Acknowledge the Sender
2. Save the email message on disk as an html file (*the same method provided as `SaveAs` option*)

For the 1st problem in order to send the email to sender, I need to fetch the sender's email address. So, I tried the following, but no luck :( doing to the below I can get the Email message in which From contains only the name not the email address.

```cs
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(email.From.Address);
```

Could anyone help me out here.

Thanks,

Ankush Gupta

Comment: So what error / problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I am unable to fetch the sender's email address. I have refined my question again.

Comment: I am able to get the sender email address using EWS. I missed to add email.Load() call, on doing so all the first class properties get loaded and I am able to fetch the Sender Address.

Comment: yes. The second one: Saving the email message on disk as an html file (the same method provided as SaveAs option)

Comment: Do you want just the body or a fancy view of the mail including things like From, To, Subject... the thing Outlook generates when you print an email?

Comment: Could you please provide me both the methods. But I might be going with the fancy view of the mail which includes From, To, Subject etc.

Comment: Is it possible to save it in HTML format?? Do EWS provides any API to achieve this.

Comment: @AnkushGupta: EWS is a server technology and therefore there is no way for EWS to save a file somewhere on your disk.  You can build the file yourself from EmailMessage.Body/.From/.To/.Subject properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the comments:

EWS does not provide you with a way to directly save a message as HTML. You can, however, get the body of the mail as HTML using this property set:

```cs
mail.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Body) {RequestedBodyType = BodyType.HTML});
```

If you want something more fancy (like the Outlook save as html functionality), you'll have to combine the body with the From, ToRecipients, CCRecipients, Subject and Received property.

Comment: If my email contains an embedded image then the saved HTML file will not able to render the image as the images are not present (since the name in the message body and saved HTML are different), even if I try to fetch the attachments but the name in the html (which I saved using file stream) is different than the one in attachment collection.
Do I need to parse the HTML and replace the image name with the one I got from the collection??